# Disable specific warnings in Stack build --pedantic

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to compile my Haskell code in Stack using all warnings except for one, `-fwarn-unused-imports`.

Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed that this works:

```
stack build --file-watch --pedantic --ghc-options -fno-warn-unused-imports
```

Note that you have to put `no` after `f`, so the ghc option for disabling it becomes `-fno-...`